# How to select recent date or max date in a column in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server, powerbi-custom-visuals

We have Date table in Power Bi in that we have to select the max date or recent date for some purpose. How to select the same.

```
DATE
01/04/2020
02/04/2020
03/04/2020
04/04/2020
05/04/2020
06/04/2020
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to MAX function in DAX, use that one to get the value

```
DATEVALUE(MAX('Table'[DATE]))
```

The result is **06/04/2020**